# Typescript syntax highlighting stopped working in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: typescript, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-2022

In one of the recent updates for Visual Studio the typescript syntax highligting stopped working. It appears to stop working after a type conversion in the code is done.

Example:

[image]

As you can see, the syntax highlighting seems to stop working after the line containing *<Services.IYearAndMonth>...*

1. The comment starting with "Common.ListManagement"... is not highlighted
2. The key word "this" is not highlighted

I'm running the following Visual Studio version:
*Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.5.5*

Comment: maybe TS thinks it's `tsx`, try `({year} as Serveces.Thing)`

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in Visual Studio 2022 17.6

More info here : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/TypeScript-Syntax-Highlight-Broken/10274299